# Drupal Form not Submitting

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

Hi Stackoverflow community,

I am creating a voting system with many categories using the FormAPI.

I built the form with drupal_get_form() and stored the html markup into a textarea in a CCK field. I also built the submit function which deals with the database.

However, when I display the node, the form can be construct however, the submission function is not called. I can't figure out the source of the problem. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

*EDIT:

Defines the form:

```
function judges_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser, $page) { 
switch ($op) {
    case 'view':

        ...

        $node->field_judging_form[0]['value']=drupal_get_form('judges_entry',($node));

        node_save($node);
}
}



  function judges_entry($form_state, $node){
    ...
    return $form;
}
```

Then I'm simply using CCK to display the form as plain text.

Comment: might help if you post some of your relevant code so we might be able to spot the problem

Comment: I think it would help as well if we could see your form code as well.

Comment: can you display the full code please

Comment: Sorry, I just thought that the actual problem isn't within the form generation, but rather how Drupal handles the forms that are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `drupal_get_form()` a new token is generated (for security reasons), so you can't render a form statically into a field and expect it to ever work.

What you need to do is get a fresh version of the form every time you display it by implementing hook_preprocess_node and then outputting the form in your template file. Something like this in your module file:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['my_form'] = drupal_get_form('judges_entry',($vars['node']));
}
```

Then in your template file (node.tpl.php):

```
echo $my_form;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this immediately!